# Type mismatch on vertex RDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

How many properties (property key:value pairs) can be stored in a GraphX vertex?

```
  val vertexArray = Array(
    (1L, ("Name", "Alice"), ("age", 28), ("major", "ECE")),
    (2L, ("Name", "John"), ("age", 23), ("major", "History")),
    (3L, ("Name", "Mark"), ("age", 34), ("major", "Education"))
  )

  val edgeArray = Array(
    Edge(1L, 3L, "cousin"),
    Edge(1L, 2L, "spouse")
  )
  val vertexRDD = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
  val edgeRDD = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)

  val graph = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)
```

the above code gives me error when I create a graph.

```
Error:(28, 21) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (String, String), (String, Int), (String, String))]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, ?)]
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, ?)]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
  val graph = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)
                    ^
```

Also, does the vertexId always has to be Long, or does graphX also support String vertexId(if I want to use java UUID)?

Comment: @yogesh.tewari Not sure why this was tagged as [tag:neo4j]. I removed it. Also: Please edit your question with your error; don't put additional details in comments.

Comment: I understand the error, just want to confirm if there is a way to store multiple properties in a graphx vertex like in a neo4j node.

Comment: That comment is the first time you've mentioned anything to do with neo4j. Regardless: It's not a neo4j question.

Comment: Hi David, i was referring to Neo4j so I thought I will tag it. but if it doesn't make sense then I will remove it. I will move the error logs in the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error indicates, a `vertexRDD` needs to be of type `RDD[(VertexId, ?)]` - in other words it must be an `RDD` of `Tuple2` where the first element must be of type `VertexId`. In your example you create an `RDD` of `Tuple4` which is not valid. To make it valid, wrap the last three elements in a Tuple3, like this:

```
 val vertexArray = Array(
  (1L, (("Name", "Alice"), ("age", 28), ("major", "ECE"))),
  (2L, (("Name", "John"), ("age", 23), ("major", "History"))),
  (3L, (("Name", "Mark"), ("age", 34), ("major", "Education"))))
```

And to answer your second question, then yes, VertexId must be a Long :)

Comment: While i am writing a test case , i am getting below error....type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[java.io.Serializable] Note: String <: java.io.Serializable, but class RDD is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5) ...what does this mean and how to fix it , please help me.

Comment: Ehm, this comment does not appear to have anything to do with this question or answer. Please post it as a new question explaining your problem in details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the 3rd argument "defaultVertexAttr"

val graph = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD, (("Name", ""), ("age", 0), ("major", "")))